# Running PowerShell script with arguments

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to run a PowerShell script with CMD without success.

The script i'm running:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command 'C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\start-tdpsql-instance.ps1' -dpsqloptfile h:\tsm\dsm.opt -dpsqlcfgfile h:\tsm\tdpsql.cfg
```

But unfortunately, i get an error message:

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:1 char:58
+ 'C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\start-tdpsql-instance.ps1' - <<<< dpsqloptfile h
:\tsm\dsm.opt -dpsqlcfgfile h:\tsm\tdpsql.cfg
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
ception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Do you have any ideas why it isn't processing my arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! =]

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& 'C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\start-tdpsql-instance.ps1' -dpsqloptfile 'h:\tsm\dsm.opt' -dpsqlcfgfile 'h:\tsm\tdpsql.cfg'
```

Comment: While this will work, this is what the `-File` argument is for. Instead of doing `-Command "&....` you can just do `-File 'script.ps1'`.

Comment: @SpellingD Actually, that won't work, because single quotes aren't valid quoting characters in CMD, but `powershell -File "script.ps1"` will.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers True, I was just focusing on the point of `-File` and not the implementation of the calling shell.